# Split x elements to y places with at least one empty.

Tags: combinatorics

i have problem with variance.

**Task:** There are 6 balls with numbers from **1 to 6**. The balls are going to be divided to 5 boxes. How many possible variants of dividing balls to boxes there are? Order in box are not important. Is needed to have always at least one box free.

```
Balls: {1,2,3,4,5,6}
Boxes: {A,B,C,D,E}
```

Enabled possibility:

```
Pos. 1: A{1,2,3} B{4,5,6} C{}  D{}  E{}
Pos. 2: A{1,2}   B{3,4}   C{5} D{6} E{}
```

Wrong possibility:

```
Pos. 3: A{1,2}   B{3}    C{4}  D{5} E{6}
Pos. 4: A{1}     B{2}    C{3}  D{4} E{5,6}
```

First step is to count all possible values, thats pretty easy.

```
5^6 = 15625
```

But i have no idea how to filter out all possibilities where are all box filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are considering that the boxes are distinguishable, so will I. As you have correctly pointed out, the number of ways of choosing boxes without any restriction is $5^6$. Now, we will discount all the unwanted choices, that is, the choices in which every box has at least one ball.

To count all choices for which there are no empty boxes, notice that you must have all boxes with exactly one ball, except one box that must contain $2$ balls. So, first you have ${6 \choose 2}$ ways to choose the pair of balls that will be together. After choosing this pair, you have fixed the content of all boxes. All you have to do is to consider the possible permutations (choose which content belongs to each box), which can be done in $5!$ ways. Thus, there are ${6 \choose 2}\cdot 5!$ ways to do so.

Finally, the number of choices for which there is at least one empty box is $5^6 - {6 \choose 2}\cdot 5! = 13825$.

Comment: Are you sure with that 6^5? I still think it should be 5^6.I have just made a program, which simulates my problem and the answer is **15625** total possibilities and **13825** possibilities with at least one empty box. So im little confused now.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I confused the values. Let me fix this

Comment: Great. Thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can think about it as the number of ways to divide six unique balls into four (also unique) boxes, and each one of those corresponds to a way of dividing the balls into boxes 1 to 4, or boxes 1 to 3 and 5, etc. So you'd have to multiply that by 5.

One more thing, you need to think about the repetitions you would get from this - for example, one of the ways to divide the balls into the first four boxes is to put them all in the first. However this is also one of the ways to divide them into all the boxes except the fourth.

So a possible approach that deals with those cases is to count all the ways to divide 5 balls into 4 boxes, times 5, then all the ways to divide 5 balls into 3 boxes, times 5 choose 2 (the 2 empty boxes), etc.